# iOS autolayout exception "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, autolayout, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a view controller and in that i have a tableview and UISearchDisplayController. 
I have added constraints in my storyboard for the subviews.

I am adding constraints to UISearchResultTableView to make its height -50 from bottom in

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
```

The problem is when I search something in UISearchBar. It throws the exception "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

I tried to add [tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; before adding constraints **but then the table do not scroll**.

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

[tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSLayoutConstraint *ccc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1
                                        constant:-50];
    [constraintsArray addObject:ccc];


   [self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

}
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you got a exception message "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints". it means that your constraints are conflicting somewhere. I think you have set the constrain of your tableview in the storyboard, but you add another constraint in your code. So it can't determine satisfy which constraint to reset the tableview's frame. Just fix it.

Comment: The constraints are added to the UISearchDisplayController in storyboard not its tableView. My issue is what constraints to add after [tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];